# Unable to delete my question, although it's not heavily viewed, not liked, and I'm the one who has answered it

Tags: support

While checking my posts, I stumbled upon [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767032/whats-the-meaning-of-project-itemgroup4-clcompile-include-in-a-visua).

It's a question I've asked myself, there are no comments, the question has been viewed only 128 times in more than 4 years, and the answer is one I've written myself.

Both the question and the answer have no upvotes but each has one downvote.

In other words: this website does not like this question. So why not let me delete it?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the check mark on the answer?

Comment: Have you tried unaccepting your answer, then delete it and then delete the question?

Comment: Canonical deletion guidance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/248731

Comment: @JeanneDark There's no need to delete the Answer first. Unaccepting the Answer will enable deletion of the Question. I know, because I've done it :)

Comment: @JeanneDark: I've unaccepted the answer, deleted the answer and then the question. Now everything is ok. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [Jeanne Dark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11682469/jeanne-dark), it can be done by first unaccepting the answer. After that, it became possible to delete the question (I have deleted my answer first, but, according to [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte), that seems even not to be necessary).